# percent escapes removed in NSData writeToURL

Tags: nsdata, nsurl

I am trying to cache an image retrieved from Flickr. In order to create a unique filename for the cached image, I use CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes to percent escape the URL. Appending that to the cache directory, I get a URL with the embedded Flickr URL properly percent escaped; but when I try to cache the image using NSData writeToURL:options:error: I get "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory" - and it shows the file URL with the original, unescaped Flickr URL where the file name should be.

For example, I NSLog the URL as:

file://localhost/Users/rick/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/77C4A7AA-C386-4575-AD21-B4027D080408/Library/Caches/http%3A%2F%2Ffarm3.static.flickr.com%2F2887%2F9391679341_26643bcafa_b.jpg

but the error message shows

NSFilePath=/Users/rick/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/77C4A7AA-C386-4575-AD21-B4027D080408/Library/Caches/http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2887/9391679341_26643bcafa_b.jpg

It's as if in the process of converting the URL to a file path, writeToURL is removing the percent escapes.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening, or do I just need to come up with another way to generate unique names based on the url?

Here's the relevant code:

```
NSURL *cacheDirectoryURL=[[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSString *photoURLString= (NSString *) CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                               (__bridge CFStringRef)([self.photoURL absoluteString]),
                                                                               NULL,
                                                                               (CFStringRef) @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                                kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
if (photoURLString)
{
    NSURL *cachedPhotoURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[[cacheDirectoryURL absoluteString] stringByAppendingString:photoURLString]];
    NSData *photoData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:cachedPhotoURL];

    if (photoData)
    {
         UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:photoData];
        self.imageView.image=image;
        [self setupScrollView]; // new image, need to adjust scroll view
    } else {
         dispatch_queue_t fetchQueue=dispatch_queue_create("photo downloader", NULL);
        dispatch_async(fetchQueue, ^{
            NSData *photoData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.photoURL];
            NSError *error;
            if ([photoData writeToURL:cachedPhotoURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error])
            {
                NSLog(@"Cached photo");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Failed to cache photo");
                NSLog(@"%@",error);
            }                
        });

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Perhaps show some code. How is the escaped path created, how is the URL created from the path, ... ?

Comment: @Martin R, I've edited the question to include the code. It may be worth noting that if I replace the code that creates the escaped URL to with code that sets the string to @"test" then the writeToURL succeeds.

Comment: I think you may be correct that `writeToURL` is removing the percent escapes. What happens if you run your `photoURLString` through `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`, effectively percent-escaping your already percent-escaped string?

Comment: @JakeSpencer: I think it is `URLWithString` that removes the percent escapes. This method should not be used for file system paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `[NSURL URLWithString:...]` parses the given string and *interprets* the
percent escapes. Generally, to create a URL for a file system path, `fileURLWithPath:`
should be used.

In your case, the following simple code should work:

```
NSURL *cachedPhotoURL = [cacheDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:photoURLString]
```